# Ajax load from LAN's mysql using chrome app

Tags: mysql, ajax, google-chrome-app

I am trying to Ajax load from LAN's mysql using chrome app.

I am proposing Ajax because I need chrome app to load up any update in the SQL instantaneously.

Since this app is only used in LAN network, I presume there is no need to maintain a web server (aka running Apache). Can anyone provide some hints as this answer I found on the forum does not help me (an absolute newbie) too much.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Thank you.

YY

Comment: If you don't use a web server, what will be the software that understands http requests you're sending?

Answer (score 1):

> Since this app is only used in LAN network, I presume there is no need to maintain a web server (aka running Apache).

AJAX refers to making a HTTP request to.. something.

Something that can answer HTTP requests is called a web server.

So, you do need *some* sort of web server. It *may* be a component of MySQL server, but it's still a web server.

---

That said, it doesn't look like MySQL has a supported HTTP interface. There is an [experimental HTTP Plugin](http://labs.mysql.com/) that provides REST API, but it's *experimental*. Therefore, you would need a separate server application that does what you need.

---

That said,

> I am proposing Ajax because I need chrome app to load up any update in the SQL instantaneously.

AJAX is not a magic bullet. It works well for requesting data, but it is not adapted to receiving updates initiated by the server you're talking to. It's a request-response cycle, and while there are [some techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) to use it to push data they are hacks.

[WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) evolved to cover the bidirectional, persistent communication needs. However, this again would require a web server to sit as a proxy between your DB and your app - this time, WebSockets-capable.

---

That said, building a Chrome App allows you to connect to a database directly - since Chrome Apps are capable of using `chrome.sockets` API. You would need a JavaScript library specifically adapted to the task, but those probably exist.

---

*That* said, and noting that I'm not an expert on databases, but..

Databases are not designed to notify you about updates. You need to poll them to see if the data has changed. You will not get it *instantaneously* no matter what interface you use. You'll need to periodically monitor it for changes.

Considering this, depending on what you're trying to ultimately do you may be choosing a wrong instrument.

---

There's a lot of "buts" here, and it seems like a complex task. You should re-evaluate your readiness as an "absolute newbie" to undertake it.